# override error android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm doing an Android development course using Android Studio but I'm getting a `@Override` error in one of the examples that I tried to copy/repeat.

Here the code where I get the error

```
Handler handler = new Handler(){
    @Override //here I get an error, that is not overriding a class
    public void handlerMessage(Message msg) {
        TextView JeroensText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.JText);
        JeroensText.setText("Lekker bezig!");
    }
};
```

Anybody how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

There's no `handlerMessage(Message message)` method on [android.os.Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) class, you should override `handleMessage(Message message)` method (without the 'r')

Answer (score 2):

In both cases:

```
    Handler handler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback () {
        @Override
        public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
            TextView JeroensText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.JText);
            JeroensText.setText("Lekker bezig!");
            return false;
        }
    });

}
```

and

```
    Handler handler  = new Handler () {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            TextView JeroensText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.JText);
            JeroensText.setText("Lekker bezig!");
        }
    };
```

as you can see there is `handleMessage()` method, not `handlerMessage()`.

Hope it help

Answer (score 0):

Its just a simple miss - remove that extra '**r**' from your hanlderMessage method.

Since there is no 'handle**r**Message(Message)' method for Handler. Use either 
with Callback

```
Handler handler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback () {
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        // handle message here
        return true;
    }
});
```

or

```
Handler handler  = new Handler () {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        // handle message herer
    }
};
```